# Update object value in array within array React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update my product attributes and i came to a solution only for one attribute.

this is my carrtItems state

```
    this.state = {
    
    cartItems: [],
    selectedAttributes: []
```

Json Object

```
{
    "__typename": "Product",
    "name": "iPhone 12 Pro",
    "inStock": true,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "__typename": "AttributeSet",
            "id": "Capacity",
            "name": "Capacity",
            "type": "text",
            "items": [
                {
                    "__typename": "Attribute",
                    "id": "512G",
                    "value": "512G"
                },
                {
                    "__typename": "Attribute",
                    "id": "1T",
                    "value": "1T"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "__typename": "AttributeSet",
            "id": "Color",
            "items": [
                {
                    "__typename": "Attribute",
                    "id": "Black",
                    "value": "#000000"
                },
                {
                    "__typename": "Attribute",
                    "id": "White",
                    "value": "#FFFFFF"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": "product1",
    "quantity": 1,
    "selectedAttributes": [
        {
            "value": "512G",
            "type": "Capacity",
            "id": "product1"
        },
        {
            "value": "#44FF03",
            "type": "Color",
            "id": "product1"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my update function:

```
      updateCartItem = (cart, product, selectedAttribute, newAttributes) => {
      const existingCartItem = cart.find(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id === product.id
      );
      
      const thisCart = cart.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id !== product.id)
      
      if (existingCartItem) {
        cart.map((cartItem) =>
          cartItem.selectedAttributes.map((attr)=> attr.type===selectedAttribute.map((newAttr)=>newAttr.type
            ? newAttributes= [{
                ...attr,
                value: newAttr.value,
              }]
            : [newAttributes = attr]
        )));
        return [
          ...thisCart,
          { ...product, selectedAttributes: newAttributes },
        ];
      }
    };
```

This is update state function

```
updateItemToCart = (product, selectedAttributes) => {
    this.setState({
      cartItems: this.updateCartItem(this.state.cartItems, product, selectedAttributes),
    });
  };
```

This my is my selected attributes functions

```
 selectAttribute = (attribute, newAttribute, type, id) => {
    const existingAttribute = attribute.find(
      (attr) => attr.type === type && attr.id === id
    );

    if (existingAttribute) {
      return attribute.map((attr) =>
        attr.type === type && attr.id === id
          ? { ...attr, value: newAttribute }
          : attr
      );
    }

    return [...attribute, { value: newAttribute, type, id }];
  };

  selectedAttributesHandler = (newAttribute, type, id) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedAttributes: this.selectAttribute(
        this.state.selectedAttributes,
        newAttribute,
        type,
        id
      ),
    });
  };
```

What i want here is to update selectedAttributes if color or size changes but to remain the other attribute.

Example:

Color: white, Size: M

Here i change the size to L on click
Result:
Color: white, Size:L

How to update updateCartItem function to achieve this result.

Comment: Please post a valid json/js state object.

Comment: @AG JSON state object updated.
That is what i get when console.log the cartItems state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

It allows you to easily populate an object or array with a shallow copy of the contect of another object or array.

The syntax is three dots followed by the name of the object or array that we want to copy.

**Example:**

```
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      selectedAttributes: this.selectAttribute(
        this.state.selectedAttributes,
        newAttribute,
        type,
        id
      ),
    });
```

There are other ways of achieving this, but this is the likely the simplest way and is a common pattern when working with `state` in React.

Comment: This is working when only one attribute. But when the product has two attributes {Color and Capacity} like the json above it is removing my other attribute which i did not change.

Comment: But you are not actually updating `selectedAttributes`, you are adding `newAttribute`, `type`, and `id` fields that are not initially part of the `state`. Is this intentional?

Comment: The idea is like this:

I added selectedAttributes object in cartItem to know which attributes member has selected also i added quantity. The other data is from productData state.
Maybe the way i added selectedAttributes is not the right way.
How would you solve that. To add selectedattributes to cartItem state so i can change later if when i select other attribute.